# Answers Half Typed for On Hold Questions

Tags: feature-request

I experienced a little frustration today whilst typing out, what I thought, was about to be a well thought through answer to a question. Although the question was badly put forward I understood what they needed and was putting together a reply which i believed would sort their problem and help anyone in the future who stumbled across the question.

So, I press the `Post Your Answer` button, and nothing happens. Damn. What's going on? I refresh the page and find out. The question was put on hold. Now, I understand and greatly appreciated the On Hold system. It does it's job well and is an asset to the site. That said, having had this happen was frustrating, but I think it's something that could be avoided fairly easily.

So, onto the feature request.

The feature request is to allow answers to be posted if someone started typing it out before the question was put on hold. This would obviously have to come with restrictions to stop exploitation, such as giving people a 5 minute or so window maximum in which they can submit an answer after it has been put on hold (as long as they started typing the answer out before the question was put on hold).

I think this would help prevent people becoming discouraged with answering others questions.

***Clarification for Moderation***: The only previous question/request on this subject has asked that all people should be allowed to post to on-hold questions and the answers will then appear later when the question is taken off-hold. Where-as I am asking that answers merely be allowed through if they were started before the question was put on hold. That makes this a request for an entirely different feature.

Comment: If you edit the question into shape it could be reopened...do you mind adding the link to the question?

Comment: shh... Don't tell anyone, but such system is already in place

Comment: This has happened to me several times before - the most common case IMO is when people are asking "dumb" questions where an educating answer actually has a lot of value. Usually the form is "How do I solve X using Y" and the answer is "You should really solve X with Z, it's much simpler".

Comment: @rene - I could, and I probably will in this instance. But this means storing my answer in a text document somewhere and having to check the post periodically to see if it has been opened again. Which, is not exactly ideal.